# Llamar a una función de un controlador en otro controlador en NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy armando una api con Nodejs, Express y MongoDB.

Llegué a un punto en el que estoy repitiendo ciertas líneas de códigos en diferentes controladores, por lo que mi pregunta es básicamente esa:
Cómo hacer la llamada de una función de un controlador en otro?

Lo que tengo, por ejemplo, es lo siguiente:

```
const getEmpresa = (req, res) => {

    let empresaId = req.params.id;

    if(!empresaId || empresacId === null) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe la empresa o no existe el ID'});

    Empresa.findById(empresaId, (err, empresa) => {
        
        if(err || !empresa) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe la Empresa'});

        return res.status(200).send({empresa});
    });
}
```

**En Empresa.findById ya lo llamo más arriba con:**

> const Empresa = require('../models/empresa');

Hasta aquí básicamente, tengo una base de datos de empresas a las cuáles voy accediendo a cada una de ellas con su respectivo ID. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Luego, tengo otro controlador donde guardo las personas que van a trabajar en las empresas, y dentro una función muy similar llamada getPersonas, que son buscadas por su Id de la misma forma que las Empresas.

Por su parte, tengo otra tabla que guarda la relación entre las Personas y las Empresas, muchas Personas pueden ir a trabajar en muchas Empresas, y muchas Empresas pueden recibir muchas Personas.

Y aquí es donde me genera la pregunta:

Este es el controlador donde guardo esa relación:

```
const newTrabajo = (req, res) => {
    let params = req.body;

    Trabajo.empresa = params.empresa;
    Trabajo.persona = params.persona;

    if(!params.empresa || !params.persona) return res.status(200).send({message: 'Falta la Empresa o la Persona'});

    Trabajo.find({'empresa': Trabajo.empresa, 'persona': Trabajo.personaa}).exec((err, trabajos) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Hubo un error tratando de obtener los trabajos'});

        if(!trabajos) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha encontrado el trabajo'});

        if(trabajos.length > 0) {
            return res.status(200).send({message: 'Este trabajo ya se guardó'});
        } else {
            let trabajo = new Trabajo();

            trabajo.empresa = params.empresa;
            trabajo.persona = params.persona;

            trabajo.save((err, trabajoStored) => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error tratando de guardar el trabajo'});

                if(!trabajoStored) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se pudo guardar el trabajo'});

                return res.status(200).send({trabajo:trabajoStored});
            });
        }
        
    });

   
}
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona perfecto. Tengo Empresas y tengo Personas y voy guardando las relaciones.
Cuando ya hay una relación entre una Empresa y una Persona, no guarda y salta el mensaje 'Este trabajo ya se guardó'.

Ahora me tocaría crear una comprobación, es decir, obtener tanto el ID de la Persona y el ID de la Empresa, para corroborar que existe y guardar correctamente en la base de datos, ya que así como está, yo puedo, por ejemplo, intercambiar IDs, poner el ID de la persona en el de Empresas y viceversa, que todo guarda perfecto.

El tema es que al momento de la comprobación, me vi escribiendo el mismo código de getEmpresa en el código del newTrabajo para revisar si ese ID es válido y quise hacer la llamada a la función getEmpresa del controlador que tengo en empresaController e insertarlo en la función newTrabajo del controlador trabajoController, de manera que devuelva un true si existe el ID de la empresa y guarde correctamente, y si no existe, que devuelva el mensaje de ese mismo controlador.

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que en la primera función llamo a los parámetros desde la url, y en la segunda, los llamo desde el body